# A message sent to your phone to erase another message

Tags: sms

After giving a new credit card to a client some banks send its PIN code with an SMS. Later they send another SMS that's only purpose is to erase the SMS with the PIN from user's phone. Does this trick work via Replace Short Message Type code and how secure is it?

Comment: What do you mean with "How secure?"? Secure against what?

Comment: @MechMK1 I think he means could we be sure that the second SMS sent has effectively deleted the first :)

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the app. It's not about security. In general, once the end user has access to any data, it is out of your control.